# python jupyter notebook 周辺密度関数を図示する

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

以下を実行し、

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, integrate
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
%precision 3
%matplotlib inline
```

```
x_range=[0,2]
y_range=[0,1]

def f_xy(x,y):
    if 0<=y<=1 and 0<=x-y<=1:
        return 4*y*(x-y)
    else:
        return 0
    
XY=[x_range,y_range,f_xy]
```

```
from functools import partial
# 周辺密度関数を定義
def f_X(x):
    return integrate.quad(partial(f_xy, x), -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
X = [x_range, f_X]
def f_Y(y):
    return integrate.quad(partial(f_xy, y), -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
Y = [y_range, f_Y]
```

```
xs=np.linspace(*x_range,100)
ys=np.linspace(*y_range,100)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)
ax1.plot(xs,[f_X(x)for x in xs],color='gray')
ax2.plot(ys,[f_Y(y)for y in ys],color='gray')
ax1.set_title('Xの周辺密度関数',fontname='MS Gothic')
ax2.set_title('Yの周辺密度関数',fontname='MS Gothic')

plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上図を出力したいです。

私は何回やっても、下図のように右側のグラフが曲線になってしまいます。
エラーメッセージは出ていません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `x_range`や`y_range`が定義されていないようですが、質問時の転記ミスでしょうか？ そうでなければ以前に実行されていた内容が残って影響している可能性があるので、いったんjupyter notebookをリセットか終了・再起動してから、それらを定義して実行してみてください。いずれにしろ質問にそれらを追記してください。

Comment: 転記ミスです。変更します。

Comment: 二つ目のかたまりが追加のコードです。

Comment: 自分でも試してみて、とりあえず、該当部分を２ｘとすれば、図示できました。もし周辺密度関数についての誤りがわかる方いらっしゃいましたら、回答いただきたいと思います。この度はご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def f_X(x):`と`def f_Y(y):`の両方で結局は`integrate.quad(partial(f_xy, x), -np.inf, np.inf)[0]`という同じ値になる関数を使っているので、結果は指定するパラメータの値に応じて(0.0から1.0までの範囲では)同じ形になると考えられます。
別の形にしたいなら、別の関数や計算式を設定して使う必要があるのでは？

周辺密度関数とか関係無しに非常に単純に図だけ描ければ良いのなら、2つ目の図の y は x の2倍なので、こちらの行を：

```
ax2.plot(ys,[f_Y(y)for y in ys],color='gray')
```

こちらに変更すれば直線の図を描くことが出来ます。

```
ax2.plot(ys,[y*2 for y in ys],color='gray')
```

併せて図の中にグリッドを表示するのと質問の問題には関係ない部分をコメントアウトするとこんな風になるでしょう。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats, integrate
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
%precision 3
%matplotlib inline

x_range=[0,2]
y_range=[0,1]

def f_xy(x,y):
    if 0<=y<=1 and 0<=x-y<=1:
        return 4*y*(x-y)
    else:
        return 0

#### XY=[x_range,y_range,f_xy]

from functools import partial
# 周辺密度関数を定義
def f_X(x):
    return integrate.quad(partial(f_xy, x), -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
#### X = [x_range, f_X]
#### def f_Y(y):
####     return integrate.quad(partial(f_xy, y), -np.inf, np.inf)[0]
#### Y = [y_range, f_Y]

xs=np.linspace(*x_range,100)
ys=np.linspace(*y_range,100)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122)
ax1.plot(xs,[f_X(x)for x in xs],color='gray')
ax2.plot(ys,[y*2 for y in ys],color='gray') #### 2つ目の図 y は x の2倍
ax1.set_title('Xの周辺密度関数',fontname='MS Gothic')
ax2.set_title('Yの周辺密度関数',fontname='MS Gothic')
ax1.grid() #### グリッド表示
ax2.grid() #### 同じく

plt.show()
```

正しく2つ目の図用の周辺密度関数を定義したいなら、`def f_Y(y):`関連の記述を復活させて、その内容を相応しいものに修正すれば良いでしょう。